# Unable to get the DBMS Logs in Oracle SQl Developer

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

I am using Oracle SQL Developer (**Version 18.4.0.376**) and Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Product PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production "CORE  10.2.0.1.0 Production" TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production.

In the SQL Query Builder the output of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` is not disabled automatically.

See the following screen shot:

[image]

Can any one suggest to me, how I can get rid of this issue?

Comment: Are you connecting as same user?DBMS output windows shows hr user in the tab not sure in your sql worksheet.

Comment: What exactly do you want to get rid of? The `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.` lines in the **Script Output** window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test);
END;
```

Then your output will look like this:

> ```
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
> Test
> ```

<sup>***Reference:*** [DBMS_OUTPUT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_output.htm#TTPLP71197) (Oracle | Docs)</sup>

If you want to get rid of the `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed` message, then you can turn if off with the command `SET FEEDBACK OFF`. The whole thing will then look like this:

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test');
END;
```

Your output will then be:

> ```
> Test
> ```

<sup>***Reference:*** [How do I Suppress “PL/SQL procedure successfully completed” message in sqlplus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250509/how-do-i-suppress-pl-sql-procedure-successfully-completed-message-in-sqlplus) (Stack Overflow)</sup>
<sup>***Reference:*** [SQLPlus® User's Guide and Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG060) (Oracle | Help Center)*</sup>